# Is there a public database for annual flights by aircraft type?

Tags: airliner, commercial-aviation, commercial-operations, datasets

I am doing research about the number of flights and distance flown performed by aircraft types, in a given year. For example:

```
There were X A320-200 flights, flying an average distance of Y nautical miles, in the year Z.
```

I know that these records are kept for all registered flights, so I am wondering if there is a database where one can find such info?

I am looking for data of as many regional flight airliners as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is "no". There is no such thing as a "registered" flight.

In cases where pilots have filed flight plans, you could aggregate that data. It would be a BIG programming project. There are commercial services that analyze flight plan data. They might be willing to help you for a price that would be in the 10's of thousands of dollars.

Flight plan data would only be good for US information. Other countries would require other data collection.

Small planes usually don't file flight plans, but you may not care about this.

Aircraft manufacturers estimate how much their planes fly around. Whether they would be willing to share this data with you, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Tyler. After doing some searching I found out that ICAO have been keeping good records from the 70's. Access to the data costs about $1000 per year for flight traffic details only, which isn't too bad I suppose.

Comment: And I also found that IATA has a substantial amount of statistics available on just this.